# Update checkbox in lwc in the js file

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm trying to update a checkbox field via javascript before the submit. I'm getting correctly the lightning input field (I can see in the console) but is not getting saved. I also tried with a text field and it's working fine.

```
handleSubmit(event){

event.preventDefault();
const fields = event.detail.fields;

fields.isSign__c = true;
fields.Customer_Name__c = 'John Adams';
console.log('fields: ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail.fields));
this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields); 
[...]
```

In the html file I have this for the checkbox (I'm don't want to show the field, it's going to be hide) but I would like to update with the submit.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="CustomObject__c" onsubmit={handleSubmit}>

 <lightning-input-field field-name="isSign__c"> </lightning-input-field>
[...]
```

Thanks in advance.

I tried with other fields and it worked but with the checkbox seems that somethins doesn't like it and I don't know why

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive, are you sure `isSign__c` is the exact field name? is your user allowed to edit the field (profile/permission sets). Do you have any triggers, workflows etc that might be setting the value back to false? Check debug log maybe?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Yes, the field name is IsSign__c. I'm testing it with the System administrator so yes, it has the permissions (I had checked also). There is no trigger, just a flow but does nothing with this field. I have checked the console log, and it seems that the value is getting ok, but when the submit is done, the value does not change.

Comment: Might be uppercase vs lowercase "i", JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: You were totally right I didn't see it!! Thank you!